# cannot assign to X because it is a 'method group'

Tags: linq, select

I was trying to practice select function in linq. 
The Code describes Pair object that hold 2 numbers. The Main is creating a list with 2 pair and I want to select the one in which the first number (n1) equals to 1 but I get the above error.

The "pair.getN1" has a compilation error.
Thanks.

```
public class Pair
{
   private int n1;
   private int n2;

    public Pair(int n1, int n2)
    {
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
    }

    public int getN1()
    {
        return this.n1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pair pair1 = new Pair(1, 2);
        Pair pair2 = new Pair(3, 4);

        List<Pair> pairList = new List<Pair>();
        pairList.Add(pair1);
        pairList.Add(pair2);

        var chosen = from pair in pairList
                     where pair.getN1 = 1
                     select pair;

        Console.WriteLine(chosen.getn1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

Comment: a classic trap in c# linq query when using sql-like notation. See Tim Schmelter's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you came from VB.NET. You don't want `=` in C# but `==`:

```
var chosen = from pair in pairList
             where pair.getN1() == 1
             select pair;
```

In VB.NET `=` can mean assignement but also comparison, in C# `=` only means assignment.

Another thing to fix is, since `getN1` is not a field or property but a method you need `()`, in Vb.NET these are optional if there is no parameter.

Comment: still no luck, now I get "Operator '==' canot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'